# Is it possible to create activity inside Java service started with adb?

Tags: java, android, adb

There is an app called scrcpy which uploads java code into /data/local/tmp/ dir on the target device and runs it's `main` function. It is cool but I can not create activity windows which are shown in recent activity list or freeform windows and use it in application. Is it possible to create an activity window from Java program started with app_process, not spawned by Android framework? I know about Android's WINDOW_SERVICE but it can not be accessed without activity's context.

Or is there a way to create activity context from app's `main` function?

Comment: No. Only the Android framework can instantiate an `Activity`.

Comment: Ok. I can not instantiate an Activity. Is it possible to create freeform or another window that is shown in Recents list?

Comment: No. The "recents list" shows only tasks. Only the Android framework can create tasks.